# Get value of an element inside a div printed by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a code in PHP that prints HTML elements based on the information we got in the database, so if we have for example 8 products the code will print 8 divs with the following elements inside

- h1 the id of this element will be the same as the product in the database
- input for client name
- buy button that send the ID of the H1 to the database

here is some code i made

```
   <?php
    
    while($row=$consulta->fetch())
    {
        ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["Imagen"];?>"style="width:12rem;height:12rem;" alt="Scotter" > 
        <br>
        <div>

        
        
        <h4 id="<?php echo $row["ID_Scooter"]; ?>"> <?php echo $row["ID_Scooter"]; ?> </h4> 
        <br>

        <?php
        echo $row["Nombre"];
        ?>

        <br>

        <?php
        echo $row["Descripcion"];
        ?>

        <br>
        
        <?php

        ?>
        <button onclick="abrir()">Alquilar</button>

        <br> 
    </div>
        <?php

    } 

?>
```

JavaScript

```
 function abrir(){
       var dialog = document.getElementById('favDialog');  
    dialog.show();
    
    var id=document.getElementById("heres is where im supposed to get the id of the id i clicked");

alert("div id is="+id);
    }
```

php assing ID for example (3,4,5,6,7) but when i click the button inside the div with id=5 it prints the id=3 no matter which button i click

Comment: the code that i have is posted now :D

Comment: I'm assuming you have some javascript which defined "abrir()". You will need to parse the ID through to that function somehow. This can be directly using php: "abrir(<?php echo $row["ID_Scooter"]; ?>)" or use javascript to find the relevant element containing the id

Comment: How about the JS? What ever "_click the 2nd the button get the element_" means, it looks like your issue is with JS, not this PHP ..?

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like this is a problem in your javascript,  which you haven't shown us. Please update the question and add the javascript

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Your code does not contain any HTML element with the ID `heres is where im supposed to get the id of the id i clicked`

Answer (score 1):

please note that you've set onclick="abrir()" without passing any specific data!

you have got 2 way to do it:

1- passing data with php:

**HTML:**

```
abrir(<?php echo $row["ID_Scooter"]; ?>)
```

**and use it in your js :**

```
function abir(id){
let id_scooter = id;
...
}
```

2- passing clicked element with js:

**HTML:**

```
onclick="abrir(this)"
```

---

**JS:**

```
function abir(el){
  let id_scooter = (el).attr(id);
  ...
  }
```